# I want to add a border to an `<h1>` tag with a `<br>` tag

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border to an `<h1>` tag but I am not able to.

```html
<h1 id="welh1">Welcome to Take Off! <br>The World's NO.1<br>Flight and Hotel Booking Website</h1>
```

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript? You add borders with CSS, so where is your CSS?

Comment: _"but I am not able to"_ - why?

Comment: Please an excerpt of your css with your #welh1 statement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use :

```
document.getElementById('welh1').style.borderStyle = 'solid';
```

for JavaScript

Or

```
#welh1 {border-style: solid}
```

for CSS

If you want more info about css borders u can visit (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)